# How to create a new pandas column with increasing sequence id, but retain same value within each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the one below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'hourOfDay':[5,5,8,8,13,13],
                 'category':['pageA','pageB','pageA','pageB','pageA','pageB'],
                })

    hourOfDay   category
0   5           pageA
1   5           pageB
2   8           pageA
3   8           pageB
4   13          pageA
5   13          pageB
```

Now, what I want is to create a new column with a monotonically increasing id. This id should be having same value within a group (hourOfDay). I'm giving the example of the expected dataframe below.

```
    hourOfDay   category    index
0           5   pageA       1
1           5   pageB       1
2           8   pageA       2
3           8   pageB       2
4          13   pageA       3
5          13   pageB       3
```

For now, we can assume that the category column can have only two values for simplicity, but it can be extended later. If I group by the hourOfDay, each separate page category within that group should get the same value assigned to it. I can do it by making two separate dataframe out of the main dataframe (filtered by category), sort it and create a new column using the `df.groupby("hourOfDay").cumcount()` method and then finally merge the two dataframe. But this approach seems way too convoluted. So, I was wondering if there's a simpler way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Are the hourOfDay always contiguous?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, it's going to be contiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need same `index` per `hourOfDay` use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df['index'] = df.groupby('hourOfDay', sort=True).ngroup() + 1
```

Or [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('hourOfDay')
df['index'] = pd.factorize(df['hourOfDay'])[0] + 1
```

Comment: It gives `0` at the end.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. But it needs a minor change. In my case I have to set sort=True, because the lower the hourOfDay is, the lower should be the value in the index column. Would you please update the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> df['index'] = df['hourOfDay'].eq(df['hourOfDay'].shift(-1)).cumsum()
>>> df
  hourOfDay category  index
0         5    pageA      1
1         5    pageB      1
2         8    pageA      2
3         8    pageB      2
4        13    pageA      3
5        13    pageB      3
>>>
```

Use `eq` and `shift` to determine whether the current value is the same as the previous value, then use `cumsum` to cumulatively sum up the `True`s and `False`s.

Comment: Thanks, this works! But I think I'll go with the other answer by @jezrael because it's more interpretable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
df['index'] = df['hourOfDay'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output:
  hourOfDay category  index
0         5    pageA      1
1         5    pageB      1
2         8    pageA      2
3         8    pageB      2
4        13    pageA      3
5        13    pageB      3
```